Deserialize an interface using Jackson
I am having trouble deserializing an interface using Jackson.
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, 
    property = "type"
)
@JsonSubTypes(
    value = [
        JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Dog::class, name = "dog"),
        JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Cat::class, name = "cat")
    ]
)
interface Animal {
    val index: Int,
    val type: AnimalType
}

enum class AnimalType(@JsonValue val type: String) {
    CAT("cat")
    DOG("dog"),
}

class Dog(...) : Animal {
    override val type: AnimalType: AnimalType.DOG
}

class Cat(...) : Animal {
    override val type: AnimalType: AnimalType.CAT
}

sealed class AnimalRequest(
    val id: UUID,
) : Animal


@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
data class CreateAnimalDto(
    val name: String,
    val animals: List<AnimalRequest> //is a list of Cats and Dogs 
) {...}

Which gives me
2024-10-09T09:50:25.778+02:00  WARN 27351 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Could not resolve type id 'cat' as a subtype of 
....AnimalRequest: Class 
....Cat not subtype of ....AnimalRequest]

And I wonder why?

Looks like some issue in the JSON to be parsed… Can you please share it here? Suspicious: Cat not subtype of ....AnimalRequest.

Well, you try to deserialize a list of AnimalRequest objects, but neither Catnor Dog are subclass of AnimalRequest. They're subtype of Animal. As @deHaar said, without json, it is difficult to know the exact problem. But your class hierarchy is already suspicious (without more context information available, at least)
